# Create a datarame from outputs of a function in python

Tags: python, pandas, function

I want to make a dataframe from all outputs from a python function. So I want to create a dataset as df. Any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd

def test(input):
    kl = len(input)
    return kl

test("kilo")
test("pound")

# initialize list of lists
data = [[4], [5]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Name"])
```

Comment: What is the real input? A list of words?

Comment: No actually, this is an example to understand the method.

Comment: well, to be able to answer we need to know how you want to call the function ;)

Comment: Lets say it is a list of words then:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this input and function:

```py
words = [['abc', 'd'], ['efgh', '']]

def test(input):
    kl = len(input)
    return kl
```

You can create the DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(words)

      0  1
0   abc  d
1  efgh
```

then [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) your function (Warning: `applymap` is slow, in this particular case (getting the length), there as much faster vectorial methods):

```
df2 = df.applymap(test)

   0  1
0  3  1
1  4  0
```

Or run your function in python before creating the DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[test(x) for x in l] for l in words])

   0  1
0  3  1
1  4  0
```

Answer (score 0):

A related approach would be to repeatedly call your function to make a list and then form the dataframe from it:

import pandas as pd
words = ['kilo', 'pound', 'ton']
def test(input):
kl = len(input)
return kl
data = [] # create empty list
for entry in words:
data.append(test(entry))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['names'])